# Why does ec2 asks for password when i use an identity file?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I use the following command and i got the code from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

```
ssh -i my-key-pair.pem ec2-user@ec2-198-51-100-1.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

I'm not sure if it's because I lost the .pem file and recreated it or what is going on here, but no matter if I use the user ubuntu, root, or ec2-user the terminal asks me for a password.

Answer (score 1):

Your local private key must be shrouded as it should be.  It can be disabled with key management tools if you really want, but not advised.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check the file permissions on your key file. Do:

```
chmod 400 my-key-pair.pem
```

and try again.

It is also likely that the key file is just the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

You have to terminate the instance and copy it with a new ssh key.  If a key is lost then access to the server is also lost.